# Is there a PS3 controller driver for Diamondback?

Tags: ros, ps3joy, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I've been using the ps3 controller driver for a project based on ROS CTurtle and I'm wondering if there is a compatible driver for ROS Diamondback. Or is the CTurtle driver compatible to Diamondback?

Thanks a lot!

Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9649/is-there-a-ps3-controller-driver-for-diamondback?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2011-04-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2011-04-06**:
Alright. Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This page here summarizes the release status of the ps3 joystick driver releases:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/joystick_drivers/Releases

Yes, the driver is available for Diamondback.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unless noted on the wiki, stable packages that existed in CTurtle should exist in Diamondback. The ps3joy package still exists in Diamondback.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1